# ERRO WCF: Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata

Tags: c#, wcf

Bom, está acontecendo esse erro, depois que eu fiz o procedimento para acessar o IIS Remotamente.

```
   Error: 

   Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:xxxx/Service.svc. 
   If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.
   For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata 

   Exchange Error    
   URI: http://localhost:xxxx/Service.svc    O metadados cont‚m uma referˆncia que nÆo pode ser resolvida: 
   'http://localhost:xxxx/Service.svc'.    
   Não havia um ponto de extremidade em escuta em http://localhost:xxxx/Service.svc capaz de aceitar a mensagem. 
   Em geral, isso ‚ causado por um endere‡o ou a‡Æo de SOAP incorreta. Consulte InnerException, se presente, para obter mais detalhes.    
   Imposs¡vel conectar-se ao servidor remoto    
   Nenhuma conexão pode ser feita porque a maquina de destino as recusou ativamente 127.0.0.1:64969

   HTTP GET Error    
   URI: http://localhost:xxxx/Service.svc    
   Erro ao baixar 'http://localhost:xxxx/Service.svc'.    
   Imposs¡vel conectar-se ao servidor remoto    
   Nenhuma conexÆo p“de ser feita porque a maquina de destino as recusou ativamente 127.0.0.1:64969
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

WEB.CONFIG

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

INTERFACE

```
  [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.18020")]
  [ServiceContract]
  public interface IServiceConfFisica

 {

[OperationContract]
[System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute()]
executeResponse executeJUP(executeRequest jup);

 }
```

Comment: Não entendi, você hospedou o serviço em um IIS remoto, mas quer acessar ele como Localhost???

Comment: Não, tenho a solução na minha maquina ela está com o IIS EXPRESS e assim quero fazer acesso remoto de outro PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que percebi, você está usando **HTTPS** no binding do webconfig, e está chamando via http pelo client, além disso, mesmo que você esteja usando https no client, o IIS localhost (desenvolvimento) normalmente não tem o certificado digital para comunicação SSL (https), faça um teste mudando o binding do webconfig para **HTTP**.

Answer (score 1):

Qual é o nome do arquivo .svc? `ServiceConfFisica.svc`?

Você está tentando abrir `http://localhost:xxxxx/Service.svc`!

Comment: Na verdade eu modifiquei o log para Service, mas é ServiceConfFisica sim